# where is the seafile nginx config?

Tags: docker, nginx, cloud

I have deployed Seafile 7 using the docker image. This worked great, so i tried to install onlyoffice to link it with seafile. I did that as described in https://manual.seafile.com/deploy/deploy/deploy/only_office.md#deployment-of-documentserver-via-subfolder. The documentserver is running (i tested that by going to mydomain.de:88). Now I have to change the config of nginx, to get the subfolder to work. But I cant because I dont know where the config is. I looked under /etc/ but there is no nginx.

Where can I find that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I did not solve the original problem. But I followed the following tutorial and finally got seafile and onlyoffice work together.
https://unixblogger.com/setup-seafile-with-osenlyoffice-on-one-docker-host/